# Oracle SQL - achieve MAX functionality in where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

Two tables:

```
ItemComment(ItemId, ItemComment, DateCommentPosted)
Item (ItemId, ItemName, ItemPrice)
```

I need itemname and price of items that have not received any comment since say last 6 months.

I know this won't work:

```
SELECT i.itemid, i.name, i.price 
  FROM Item i, ItemComment c
 WHERE i.itemid = c.itemid 
   AND Max(c.dateCommentPosted) < (add_months(SYSDATE,-6));
```

There are answers to similar things on StackOverflow, but Oracle is not liking it.  Any Oracle-specific thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select i.itemid, i.name, i.price
  from Item i 
 where not exists (
     select 1
       from ItemComment c
      where c.dateCommentPosted between (SYSDATE - 180) and SYSDATE
        and c.itemid = i.itemid
 )
```

Answer (score 9):

Using the preferred explicit JOIN notation and the GROUP BY and HAVING clauses, you should be able to use:

```
SELECT i.itemid, i.name, i.price 
  FROM Item i
  JOIN ItemComment c ON i.itemid = c.itemid
 GROUP BY i.itemid, i.name, i.price
HAVING MAX(c.dateCommentPosted) < (ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6));
```

You could also write a sub-query, either using a WITH clause or directly in the FROM list, to calculate the most recent date that a comment was posted for each item and then join that with the Item table.

You might want to consider whether items without any comments should be selected or not.

> What if I want to show/select `Max(c.dateCommentPosted)` too. Is that an option? If I add that in the select clause and add `dateCommentPosted` in the GROUP BY clause, would that be correct?

Add it to the select clause, but not the GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT i.itemid, i.name, i.price, MAX(c.dateCommentPosted) AS dateCommentPosted
  FROM Item i
  JOIN ItemComment c ON i.itemid = c.itemid
 GROUP BY i.itemid, i.name, i.price
HAVING MAX(c.dateCommentPosted) < (ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -6));
```

You might prefer to leave the AS out.  AFAIK, Oracle absolutely rejects AS in table aliases (so I left it out there), but it accepts (but does not require) it in 'column aliases' in the select-list.

Incidentally, the SQL Standard, and therefore 'all' SQL DBMS, require aggregate comparisons in the HAVING clause, and the HAVING clause requires a GROUP BY clause.  Hence, GBH — Group By / Having as well as Grievous Bodily Harm.

Comment: what if I want to show/select Max(c.dateCommentPosted) too. Is that an option? If I add that in select clause and add dateCommentPosted in GROUP BY clause, would that be correct?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of another way to do it:

```
with cte as (
  select i.itemid,
    max(DateCommentPosted) as LastCommentDate
  from Item i left join ItemComment c on c.itemid = i.itemid
  group by i.itemid
)
select i.itemid, i.ItemName, i.ItemPrice 
from Item i join cte c on c.itemid = i.itemid
where LastCommentDate is null or LastCommentDate < add_months(SYSDATE,-6)
```

See it in action on sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/62147/2). You could also easily return the last comment date for each item this way.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it isn't the optimal solution to this particular query, but based on the actual question title what you're looking for is the `HAVING` statement, which allows you to put aggregates into the `WHERE` clause

http://psoug.org/reference/group_by.html